# Problem getting to work with images in google app engine in development server

Tags: google-app-engine

```
* 1. Download the Windows installer from the PIL website.
* 2. Double click on the installer to start the installation process.
* 3. Choose the correct directory for PIL install.
* 4. Finish the installation and test out our sample application locally.
```

These are instructions from google website.
but what is the "Choose the correct directory for PIL install." correct directory?
is in the python lib? in the google app engine? or somewhere else?

I can't get to work with images locally:

my code:

```
def upload(input):

items = input['items']

for item in items:
    img = images.resize(item['image'], 300, 300)


return img
```

I've installed the PIL in the c:\python dir and then I copyed the folder in my project root. still doesnt work! :s

the error I got is:

"D:\Totty\webDevelopment\TottysWorld\src\app\services\images\upload.py", line 11, in upload
    img = images.resize(item['image'], 300, 300)
,  File "C:\GAE\google\appengine\api\images_*init*_.py", line 633, in resize
    return image.execute_transforms(output_encoding=output_encoding)
,  File "C:\GAE\google\appengine\api\images_*init*_.py", line 521, in execute_transforms
    response)
,  File "C:\GAE\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 78, in MakeSyncCall
    return apiproxy.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
,  File "C:\GAE\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 278, in MakeSyncCall
    rpc.CheckSuccess()
,  File "C:\GAE\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_rpc.py", line 149, in _WaitImpl
    self.request, self.response)
,  File "C:\GAE\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub.py", line 80, in MakeSyncCall
    method(request, response)
,  File "C:\GAE\google\appengine\api\images\images_stub.py", line 196, in _Dynamic_Transform
    response_value = self._EncodeImage(new_image, request.output())
,  File "C:\GAE\google\appengine\api\images\images_stub.py", line 227, in _EncodeImage
    image.save(image_string, image_encoding)
,  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1439, in save
,  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py", line 564, in _save
,SystemError: Parent module 'PIL' not loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PIL must be installed into the Python installation path. Let's say you've installed Python 2.5 to C:\Python, then installation path for PIL should be 'C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\'.

Also you don't have to copy PIL directory to project root when you install it right into the python directory.